# How do I download YouTube videos in a for loop (for every link) with pytube?

Tags: python, reddit, praw, pytube

So I have a for loop with a lot of YouTube links, and I want to download them in that loop. There is an error that says 'Unavailable Video' when I do this:

```
for post in hot_posts:
    yt = YouTube(post.url)
    yt.download()
```

So let me explain this code, I'm using PRAW to get hot posts from Reddit, and I want to download them in a for loop. hot_posts is a variable for 25 hot posts and post.url is the url of the post.

When I remove the for loop and put a link in the YouTube() part, it works perfectly. I've also tried str(post.url) to make sure it's a string.

How does this work in a for loop???

Comment: I suggest using a `try`-`except` block to catch the exception that is raised when a download fails. Unfortunately, your question doesn't include enough detail to determine which exception is being raised, and from which line.

Answer (score 0):

Using pytube3 you can do download like: `yt.streams.get_highest_resolution().download()`

Answer (score 0):

This error is raised in some cases if you are using an older version of pytube. Try this:

```
python -m pip uninstall pytube pytube3 pytubex pytube4
```

then:

```
pip install pytube
```